# How to run linux application in background which uses shell?

Tags: linux, shell, background-process

I have an application/binary from a C program which by defaults uses the shell to take inputs from the user. So, when I start the application in background using `&` it stops automatically, because of the implementation on which I have no access. When I run this code

```
iStatus = system("./flute-static -send -a232.0.0.1/6666 a.txt &");
```

It gives output `[1] 21970`, the pid.

Then if I press another enter, it gives output

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ./flute-static -send -a232.0.0.1/6666 a.txt
```

And obviously it fails to send the data. How can I solve the problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can start the process in the foreground (without the &) then send it to background after entering the credentials (under bash: press ctrl-z, then type bg followed by return). but this is not programming question...

Comment: This isn't a programming question and belongs on the [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. But the answer is probably that you're trying to do something that doesn't make sense--if the program needs to read input from stdin, you'll need to attach its stdin to something that provides that input.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Actually I am running it from a c program with system() function. I have modified the question. @sergio now can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `nohup`

```
iStatus = system("nohup ./flute-static -send -a232.0.0.1/6666 a.txt &");
```

Nohup means: do not terminate this process even when the stty is cut off.

Or You can use `screen`

https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it gave the following error "[2]-  Exit 255                nohup ./flute-static -send -a232.0.0.1/6666 JFlute.1.2.tar.gz".

Answer (score 0):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and about the [fork system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29); you surely want to use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) with some other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and/or perhaps [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) and/or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html). Perhaps using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on the `flute-static` program might help you understand more of it.

BTW, you might use some [FLUTE library](http://mad.cs.tut.fi/index.html) (compile MAD-ALCLIB from its source code!), or simply use an HTTP & FTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Whatever you do, if a backgrounded process is reading stdin, it is stopped (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) etc...)! Read also the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

Comment: Thanks. I MUST use flute protocol and the binary available in the link you provided, doesn't work in fedora 19. I am using another binary. And it would be very helpful if you explain your 1st point a little bit.

Comment: You need to take several hours to read the references. I don't have a lot of time (hours or days) to explain you what is very nicely explained in a lot of books and resources.